# Go Initialization operator, package scoped variables - confused:

Tags: variables, types, go, initialization

The following code works correctly - output: `You chose Test 1`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type TNameMap map[int]string

var nameMap TNameMap

func init() {

    nameMap = make(TNameMap)
    nameMap[1] = "You chose Test 1"
    nameMap[2] = "You chose Test 2"
    nameMap[3] = "You chose Test 3"

}

func main() {

    fmt.Println(nameMap[1])

}
```

If I comment out the first line in `init()`  i.e  `//nameMap = make(TNameMap)` , I get a panic when `main()` runs, because `nameMap` was never initialized:

`panic: runtime error: assignment to entry in nil map`

**But** - if in `init()` I write `nameMap := make(TNameMap)`

instead of `nameMap = make(TNameMap)` , I get no panic, but also no output - `main()` simply runs and process terminates.

I understand that if I use the Initialization operator -  `nameMap := make(TNameMap)` - I have declared a new variable `nameMap` that is scoped only to the `init()` function and so only the package level variable  `var nameMap TNameMap` is in scope for `main()`, resulting in no output, because the package level `var` holds no map data.

But, I am confused: Why don't I get the `panic` in that situation? If  `main()` is making the call on the package var, it was never initialized - so why no `panic`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Go spec:

> A nil map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be
>   added.

This means that you can **read** from a nil map, but not **write**. Just like the panic says "**assignment** to entry in nil map". If you comment out just the line `nameMap = make(TNameMap)` it will crash because you attempt to write to it in `init` (which is where the panic happens). If you comment out the entirety of `init` the Println will not crash because you're permitted to access (read from) a nil map.

Changing the assignment to a declaration is just masking the real issue here, what's happening is it's making all the assignments valid, and then discarding the result. As long as you make the assignments valid (either by removing them or making a temporary variable), then you will observe the same behavior in Println.

The value returned by a nil map is always the zero value of the value type of the map. So a `map[T]string` returns `""`, a `map[T]int` returns `0`, and so on. (Of course, if you check with `val,ok := nilMap[key]` then `ok` will be false).

Comment: Yup - excellent. I neglected to read, understand the call stack in the panic message: **main.init·1()**
 /home/DevGo/GoHacking/main.go:14 +0x47 - panic is coming from `init()`, not `main()`

Comment: Still, IMO a bit of odd behavior here in GoLang... AFAIK, in other compiled languages you would normally blow up even if you just referenced it for reading.

Comment: There is precedence in Go. You can call methods on nil pointers too, which is useful for things like recursive tree traversal (just make sure you check that the receiver is nil). I certainly expected reading a nil map to panic too, though.

Comment: Yes, panic message itself says it: "assignment to entry in nil map", i.e. the problem was the writing, not the reading, as per your answer, but since init() runs first, maybe the panic messages are no proof of what would have happened if main() had run. But I tested it - commented out everything in init() and it ran without the panic, as per your quote. Besides, before writing to the map, you have to read it and 'touch it' - so it should have blown up then, not only with the assignment.